# Struggling with Indenting Region

Tags: emacs

I can't get Emacs to indent a region. I have tried everything and the region (that I have marked) never gets indented.

```
1. quick brown fox
2. quick brown fox
```

- Move cursor to `1`.
- Hit <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>: Emacs highlights the two lines.
- Hit <kbd>C-M-\</kbd>: I get a nice message "Indenting Region...Done".

But nothing gets indented. Am I doing something stupid?

I even ran the command via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `indent-region` and the selected region never gets indented.

Comment: Indentation behaviours are almost always determined by the major mode, so you need to tell us which major mode you are using (and bear in mind that in other modes things could work differently).

Comment: The question is a reasonable one, and shouldn't be closed IMO. The only thing a bit unreasonable is that @roshan apparently didn't look to the doc for the answer. The doc immediately says that it depends on the mode etc. A newbie could easily expect that it would always indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a numeric prefix arg to tell `indent-region` how many columns to indent: `C-3 indent-region` indents 3 columns (chars); `C-- 2` indents -2 columns (i.e., it reduces the indentation by 2 columns); and so on.

The behavior of `indent-region` depends on the mode you are in. `C-h f indent-region` tells you that with no prefix arg it has the effect of hitting `TAB` on each line in the region. If you are in a mode where `TAB` indents in such a way that it does not indent either of those lines, then they are not indented. See the Emacs manual, node `Indentation Commands`.